# Was Queen of Sheba black?

Tags: solomon, 1-kings

If you guys don't know, she's the queen that quizzed Solomon to discover his wisdom in 1 Kings 10. Was Sheba located somewhere in Africa? (I heard some theories that Sheba was Arabia but I'm skeptical of this).

Answer (score 1):

There are two "Sheba"s in the Bible. One is a descendant of Cush (Ethiopia). This Cush is probably somewhere near there.

The other is a decendant of Shem. The Semite Sheba's brothers include Ophir and Havilah.

Ophir and Havila are places accessible from King Solomon's Red Sea port Etzion Geber (near Eilat/Aqaba today) It would make sense that the Semite Sheba is somewhere on the Red Sea.

It could well be that the two Shebas refer to the same nation, which had a mixture of Semite and Hamite characteristics. Indeed, there was much trade and interface across the Red Sea strait.

This fits well with the Ethopian tradition that King Solomon had a son with the Queen of Sheba, Menelik, who is the progenitor of the Ethiopian Monarchy. There is much evidence that the Queen was dark and not Nordic, Chinese, or West African.

Comment: Havilah is somewhere in Saudi Arabia right?

Comment: It may or may not be on the Arabian peninsula's coast.